# AttributeError: move_to requires a WebElement

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am getting error AttributeError on action.drag_and_drop_by_offset by using Page Object Model on setSignature.

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

class SignaturePage:

```
signatureCanvas = "canvas_signature"
btn_go_back = "//*[@id='mobile-wrapper']/main/section/a"
btn_draw_signature = "//*[@id='mobile-wrapper']/main/article[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a"
canvas = "//*[@id='canvas_signature']"

def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver


def btngoBack(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.btn_go_back).click()


def btnDrawSignature(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.btn_draw_signature).click()


def setSignature(self):
    box = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(self.canvas)
    action = ActionChains(self.driver)
    action.drag_and_drop_by_offset(box, 200, 0)
    action.perform()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is present here

```
drag_and_drop_by_offset(box, 200, 0)
```

you are passing `box` which is a `list of web element`, not a **single web element** since you've used `find_elements` here `box = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(self.canvas)`

Just change that to `find_element` and you should be good to go.

**Note:**

```
find_elements : returns a list of web element. 
find_element : returns a single web element.
```